# Проблемы с кодировкой PHP � � �

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

У меня есть код-велосипед который определяет, является ли строка палиндромом или нет:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=pal.php method="get">
<input type="text" name="str">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['str']))
{$k=0;$n=0;
     $xr=$_GET['str'];

    if($xr == convert_cyr_string($xr , 'w' , 'k'))
    {
        $n=1;
    }
    else
        $n=2;

     $x=str_replace(" ","",$xr);

    echo "dlina: ".strlen($x)/$n."<br>";

        for ($i=0;$i<strlen($x)/$n;$i++)
          {
        #echo $x[$i]."<br>";

             if ($x[$i]==$x[strlen($x)/$n-$i-1])
             $k++;
              echo $x[$i]."<br>";
           }
           if ($k==strlen($x)/$n)
            echo "PALINDROM";
            else echo "ne palindrom<br>";
    


    $backurl="http://s2.localhost/project1/php/send_list/pal.php";
    print "<script language='Javascript'><!--
function reload() {location = \"$backurl\"}; setTimeout('reload()', 10000);
//--></script>";
}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Проблема в том, что работает только с латинскими буквами.
У меня там в конце стоит вывод каждого символа в новой строке, так вот с латинскими буквами все окей, а если ввести строку на русском языке то оно будет выводить сплошные �
И соответственно палиндром оно в русских строках не находит.

Answer (score 2):

Извините за глупый вариант, но вы проверьте кодировку самого файла? У меня такая беда была из-за этого.

Comment: Проверил, не помогло)

Answer (score 1):

Кодировку смотрите. Да и учтывайте что латынь 1символ-1бит а кирилица 2бита. Тут кодировка скорее всего win 1251

Answer (score 0):

Попробовать определить кодировку можно через подобные сайты
https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/
После этого вывести явно через iconv

Если вы получаете данные из базы проверьте кодировку в базе (у меня было что оригинальной базы выводиться все нормально а из копии хоть ты убейся русские слова не отображались корректно, так и не решил проблему)

Также проверьте кодировку файла.

Comment: Кодировка абсолютно везде UTF-8, даже iconv не помогает.

Comment: @soloway0000, откуда получаете данные для вывода?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте указать кодировку конкретно для формы `<form action="pal.php" method="get" accept-charset="UTF-8">` ну и кодировка pal.php тоже должна быть в UTF-8.